# Understanding WebElement.findElement() and XPATH

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want to use the `WebElement.findElement()` API to locate a node inside the parent node using XPATH `//span[@class='child-class']`. I thought this would return me the `<div>` that is inside the parent. However, it is returning me the first one it found in the entire DOM tree. Did I use the wrong XPATH?

I have also tried using `.//span[@class='child-class']` as the XPATH, but that does return anything.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

given the HTML below, I want to define a locator for the child-title `<span>` and child-date `<span>` and locate them using WebElement.findElement() API regardless of the parent being "//a/li[1]" or "//a/li[2]"

```
<a>
    <li> parent 1
        <div>
            <span class="child-title child-style">title 1</span>
            <span class="child-date child-style"> date 1</span>
            <span class="child-author">author 1</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</a>
<a>
    <li> parent 2
        <div>
            <span class="child-title child-style">title 2</span>
            <span class="child-date child-style"> date 2</span>
            <span class="child-author">author 3</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</a>
<a>
    <li> parent 3
        <div>
            <span class="child-title child-style">title 3</span>
            <span class="child-date child-style"> date 3</span>
            <span class="child-author">author 3</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</a>
```

I have a `WebElement parent2` initialized and located using `"//a/li[2]"`,

`WebElement child = parent2.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='child-author']"));` would give me "author 1"

`WebElement child = parent2.findElement(By.xpath("span[@class='child-author']"));` would give me `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: OK, after your edit, this question is nonsense! Most of the XPaths you refer to in your question do not exist in the sample HTML you provided. There is no `//span[@class='child-class']` anywhere, there is no `//a/li[2]` anywhere. Which would actually explain the `NoSuchElementException`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are my 2 comments with your sample code

1 - With your posted HTML, the xpath //a/li[2] is not found (we only have 3 elements with //a/li[1])

2 - Assume that we do have right code, you need to understand the differences between single slash and double slash in Xpath

```
a/b (single slash): select element that has "tag b" and "stands right after" an element that has "a tag"
```

E.g.:

```
<a>
    <b>
          <d>
               <c>
               </c>
          </d>
    </b>
</a>
```

AND

```
a//b (double slash): select element that has "tag b" and is n-level-child an element that has "a tag"
```

E.g.:

```
<a>
    <c>
          <d>
               <b>
               </b>
          </d>
    </c>
</a>
```

So, with your code

```
<a>
<li> parent 1
    <div>
        <span class="child-title child-style">title 1</span>
        <span class="child-date child-style"> date 1</span>
        <span class="child-author">author 1</span>
    </div>
</li>
</a>
```

If you want to get Date Info, you should use

```
WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/li"));
WebElement date = parent.findElement(By.xpath("div/span[contains(@class, 'child-date')]"));
WebElement date = parent.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'child-date')]"));
```

The code

```
WebElement date = parent.findElement(By.xpath("span[contains(@class, 'child-date')]"));
```

Will bring out NoSuchElementException because there is no [span] tag right after [li] tag

Hope help

Answer (score 16):

Try something like:
Use `dot(.)` before double `slash(//)`

It looks for child under the given parent element.

Answer (score 3):

Completely new question ... completely new answer. :(

Try something like:

```
WebElement parent1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[1]/li"));   // use a[2] for parent2
WebElement author = parent1.findElement(By.xpath("span[@class='child-author']"));
WebElement date = parent1.findElement(By.xpath("span[contains(@class, 'child-date')]"));
WebElement title = parent1.findElement(By.xpath("span[contains(@class, 'child-title')]"));
```

Comment: I have tried removing the "//" in my XPATH locator, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like :

```
//a/li[contains(text(), 'parent 1')]/div
```

It requests for "the `<div>` inside a `<li>` whose text contains 'parent 1' and who is inside a `<a>`.
It might not work if you have more parents because it works with a `contains()` (this xpath would also select `<li> parent 10 ... </li>`). It would be better if "parent x" were an attribute of the `<li>` instead of its text.