# Selenium Xpath: Can Store Label but not Span

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have the following piece of HTML on a page:

```
        <li class="underline group">
          <label class="p-left">P</label><span class="p-right">1111</span>
        </li>
```

The following selenium commands work fine:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>//li[2]/label</td>
    <td>tmp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${tmp}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

The following should work but doesn't:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>//li[2]/span</td>
    <td>tmp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${tmp}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

The only solution I have found is `//li[2]/span[@class='p-right']` but is this the case? Why doesn't `//li[2]/span` work by default?

Comment: Specify "doesn't work": what does `//li[2]/span` give you?

Comment: Xpath is the most fragile. cssSelector would give you greater flexibility.  Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li:nth-child(2) > span")).text.         Using the css selector guarantees that if the structure changes your code will still work.

Comment: Read my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661222/understanding-webelement-findelement-and-xpath/24668202#24668202 to understand more about single slash and double slash in Xpath

Comment: @LarsH Doesn't work in selenium. Doesn't store the text of the element, even though Xpath should return the correct element.

Comment: @bcar: I'm interested to know how that css selector would be more adaptable than the XPath expression. They seem pretty much equivalent.

Comment: @maythesource.com: what `//li[2]/span` *should* do is pretty clear. My question is, what does it actually do (what actual output do you see)? It sounds like maybe you're saying that `//li[2]/span` yields an empty string as the value of `${tmp}`. As opposed to throwing an error, or displaying 'P', for example.

Comment: @LarsH if the structure of your page ever changes the xpath is screwed where as if your structure changes but your selectors (e.g. class) dont, your code will still work.

Comment: @LarsH Yes, //li[2]/span yields an empty string as the value of ${tmp} which is very frustrating since it should work. Has anyone else had an experience like this?

Comment: @bcar: That XPath expression and that css selector will both select a span that is a (direct) child of a li that is a second sibling, anywhere in the document. Seems to me that both forms are equally (in)dependent of the structure of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would look for is, is there an earlier `//li[2]/span` in the document, before the `<li class="underline group">...<span>` that you're looking for, and the earlier `span` doesn't have the class="p-right", and also has no text content? So `${tmp}` is given the text value of that first selected `//li[2]/span`, and not the one you're trying to select? That would explain the results you're seeing, including your observation that `//li[2]//span` also "does not work." Have you tried evaluating `//li[2]/span` in a browser debugger to see which `<span>` it selects first?

If that doesn't expose an explanation ... Unfortunately it's come up a few times in my experience that Selenium doesn't quite implement the XPath spec correctly. I don't know why and I agree it's frustrating. However, I think it's helpful to know that it's likely a problem with Selenium in this case, rather than a faulty understanding of XPath on your part.

If you don't find an explanation like the one outlined in the first paragraph, you'll likely have to settle for a workaround. Thankfully, you have already found a workaround in this case, using `//li[2]/span[@class='p-right']`.

Comment: I've tried using other an online x-path tester, and the correct element is selected ( http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html ). I will try a few more but I think I agree with you that selenium ide is a bit broken in relation to xpath.

Comment: and in general... lots of bugs. They need to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `//li[2]//span`, that should do it.

Comment: @maythesource.com: When you report that something "does not work," please consider telling us what actually happened, since you have access to that diagnostic information, and we don't.

Comment: @LarsH Well in this case it's not that much information. A blank string is stored instead of storing the actual content inside span. For the label through the actual content is stored. Why there should be a difference between and label and span?

Comment: @maythesource.com: The information that it's a blank string, as opposed to the wrong non-blank string, or an error, can be crucial. Why the difference between label and span... I don't know; it's possible that seeing more of the HTML, e.g. what earlier `li`s and `spans` there are, we could tell.