# Is there a way to tell webdriver to treat a specific node on a page as a relative root node?

Tags: java, webdriver

The web app that I am using has very complex pages with many states.  To make this more manageable, I'd like to be able to chunk out major sections of the page into "sub-pages" and tell webdriver to treat them as a relative root of the document so that stray elements don't have the possibility of being picked up.  At first I thought that I could use [driver.switchTo().frame(WebElement)](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#frame(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)) but that appears be intended for iframes.

Edit:  The pages that I'm working with are divided into a couple major nodes, for the sake of example lets say I have a header and body node, which are each huge trees of elements.  Instead of telling every WebElement to specifically be a child of one of them, I'd like to create a parent page for things common to both, but then two child page objects that alone represent only the header, and only the body content.  This would let me simplify my xpath or css selectors and reduce the possibility of programmer error in having some unwanted nodes showing up in element lookups.

Functions within these page objects would return instances of each other for when it's time for control to move to a different section of the greater page.

Comment: can you clarify with an example of the concept of page and sub page ? What operations do you need to perform on the sub tree ? By the way you described it my 1st idea was to make a selection using xpath and working later on each sub tree

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661222/understanding-webelement-findelement-and-xpath) Stackoverflow Q&A.